# Jquery .clone() causing $.post to fail

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I copied HTML using .clone(true, true) because I want to keep the JQuery event handlers.  When I pass this to PHP via $.post the post fails and gives me the following error in firebug

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument" nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)" location: "JS frame :: jquery-1.7.2.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 7740" data: no]
```

I want to somehow keep the HTML and its JQuery event handlers because I am working on writing a script to save the state the user is in.

**UPDATE (Added Code)**

```
//Save HTML w/ JQuery
GSaveState = new Object();
GSaveState['HTML'] = $('#content').clone(true, true);

$.post("DecoPOState.php", { SavedState: GSaveState},
        function(data){
            alert("Test");
        }
    );
```

Comment: Well I was just going to save the response clone gave me in mySQL after I serialize() it

Comment: Fyi, `{}` is the better way to create an empty object instead of `new Object()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you try to send a DOM element - you cannot do that for obvious reasons. Assuming that you want to send the HTML code of that element, use `$('#content').html()`

```
var GSaveState = {
    HTML: $('#content').html();
};
```

However, event handlers are not contained in that string since they are attached to the element and not inline event (i.e. they aren't attributes that appear in the DOM tree).

To save the application's state event handlers should not be important at all though. Use variables for the state information you want to save and include them in your POST data.

Comment: okay so is there anyway to pass which elements have JQuery event handlers? So I can re initialize on a  reload?

Comment: You could save e.g. the IDs of those elements in an array and send that array.

Comment: I know I can easily get the ID's and what type of event but is there an easy way to get the function they trigger and pass that along too or am I over thinking?  I want to make it  dynamic as possible

Comment: You do not want to send internal details like that to your server at all. The function is most likely not dynamically generated JavaScript code, is it?

Comment: I just thought there be an easy way to re instate the JQuery handlers so I could use this code in other forms without actually going in and hard coding JQuery events when I load teh save html